# Extracting a binary boundary image for object of interest in a binary object mask image extracted from an instance segmentation mask

Tags: python, image-processing, deep-learning, computer-vision, image-segmentation

I have an instance segmentation + 2D bounding box structure from [Detectron 2](https://github.com/facebookresearch/detectron2) from which I converted the pred_masks into a binary object (of interest) mask.

So, here, my question is how can I convert this binary mask to a binary image wherein the entire image is black but the boundary around the object of interest in the object  mask is white?

```
segmenter = get_pointrend_predictor()
instances = segmenter(image)["instances"]
vis = PointRendVisualizer(image, metadata=MetadataCatalog.get("coco_2017_val"))
Image.fromarray(vis.draw_instance_predictions(instances.to("cpu")).get_image())
```

[image]

instances[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N8v0Y.png).pred_masks.shape

```
torch.Size([1, 224, 400])
na = instances[1].pred_masks.to('cpu').numpy()
print(na.shape)
```

> (1, 224, 400)

```
na = na.reshape(224, 400)
na.shape
```

> (224, 400)

```
na = np.where(na == False, 0, na)
na = np.where(na == True, 255, na)
plt.imshow(na)
```

[image]

In this specific example, I am interested in drawing a white line on the boundary of the baby elephant (which is my second instance in the instance segmentation mask object).

Unfortunately, I don't have a drawing of the boundary for the baby elephant but here's an example for the boundary of human (shown in white line):
[image]
^ image reference: https://www.programmersought.com/article/52814639867/

Comment: apply edge detection on your binary image

Answer (score 0):

I just figure out the way to extract edges of a bit mask.

As those depicted in the picture:
[image]

```
na = outputs['instances'][1].pred_masks.to('cpu').numpy()
na = na.reshape(1024, 683)

from detectron2.utils.visualizer import GenericMask
gm = GenericMask(na, 1024, 683)
sg = gm.polygons[0].reshape(-1,2)
print(sg)
```

By the code I got a list of polygon edges. It's a mask for a balloon.

To verify it, I translated the polygon into JavaScript, as in the following picture, and ran it. Obviously it works.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Morphological operations (dilation or erosion) turn out to be very handy in boundary extraction:

```
import cv2
seg_mask = cv2.imread('images/seg_mask.png', 0) # this is your segmentation mask
dilated_seg_mask = cv2.dilate(seg_mask, kernel, iterations=1)
plt.figure(figsize=(12,5))
plt.subplot(121), plt.imshow(seg_mask, cmap='viridis'), plt.axis('off'), plt.title('segmentation mask', size=20)
plt.subplot(122), plt.imshow(dilated_seg_mask-seg_mask, cmap='gray'), plt.axis('off'), plt.title('extracted boundary', size=20)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image]